# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake error when sending request from Apache Tomcat 9.0.54

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

I have moved my website from a very old server to a new server that supports SSL, and upgraded from Apache Tomcat 6 to Apache Tomcat 9.0.54 . Now when code running on my server tries to send a request to the trustspot server (trusted review site) using this code

```java
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    
        this.order=order;
        String dataForHmac      = MERCHANT_ID + order.getOrderId() + order.getCustomerEmail();
        String calculatedHmac   = base64sha256(dataForHmac, SECRET_KEY);
        order.setHmac(calculatedHmac);
        order.setKey(API_KEY);
    
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(order));
    
        String jsonData = gson.toJson(order);
    
        url = new URL("https://trustspot.io/api/pub/new_order_product");
        httpMethod = new HttpPost(url.toExternalForm());
        httpMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonData);
        httpMethod.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpMethod);
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        BufferedReader rd;
        rd = new BufferedReader(is);
    
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        StringWriter messageBody = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(messageBody);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        Email.sendAlert("Unable to send trustpot review request:"+ order.getCustomerEmail(), messageBody.toString());
    }
```

I get

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
```

How do I resolve this?

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1911)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2012)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at com.jthink.store.trustspot.TrustSpotProductRequest.sendRequest(TrustSpotProductRequest.java:68)
        at com.jthink.store.googleprocess.AbstractCreateAndSendLicense.requestReview(AbstractCreateAndSendLicense.java:306)
        at com.jthink.store.googleprocess.CreateAndSendSongKongLicense.createAndSendLicense(CreateAndSendSongKongLicense.java:120)
        at com.jthink.store.action.VerifyPaymentEJunkie.processEachItem(VerifyPaymentEJunkie.java:169)
        at com.jthink.store.action.VerifyPaymentEJunkie.handleRequest(VerifyPaymentEJunkie.java:82)
        at com.jthink.store.JThinkStoreServlet.doGet(JThinkStoreServlet.java:45)
        at com.jthink.store.JThinkStoreServlet.doPost(JThinkStoreServlet.java:32)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
```

I'm using Java 1.8.0_161-b12

Tried restarting Tomcat after setting `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1` and `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2` but made no difference

**Update**
added a main() to the class so now I can run test on machine outside of tomcat and it fails in exact same way

```
java -classpath classes:lib/*  com.jthink.store.trustspot.TrustSpotProductRequest -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1
```

gives same exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
```

running the exact same code on my PC works fine.

**Update 2**

With the `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1621095199 bytes = { 214, 189, 173, 184, 228, 255, 156, 82, 153, 122, 143, 245, 185, 144, 166, 172, 32, 10, 144, 123, 158, 248, 38, 4, 84, 67, 13, 79 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=trustspot.io]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 146
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

On my PC the difference I can see is that is also has Extension *elliptic_curves* and Extension *ec_point_formats*, do I require them ?

Also the length of the handshake is different.

```
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=trustspot.io]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 214
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 91
```

Comment: (1) `-Dsysprop=value` like other JVM options only works if given before the main-class name (or -jar, or -m/--module) on the `java` command; but (2) `https.protocols` doesn't normally affect Apache HttpClient anyway, only `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` and (3) if it did, `TLSv1` (meaning 1.0) would not help at all, because that server accepts ONLY 1.2 and 1.3, not lower. (4) It _might_ be SNI; try running with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` (before the mainclass!) and see if your client-hello has (correct) server_name.

Comment: Thanks, okay added the end of the output to question, (also moved the location of the tls option and tried a few options but as you say made no difference)

Comment: My server doesnt support some of the cipher suites, could it be that I dont have any of the cipher suites supported by the server ?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 on my PC the difference I can see is that is also has Extension elliptic_curves and Extension ec_point_formats, do I require them ?

Also the length of the handshake is different.

Comment: To be exact, your first=bad case doesn't have any suites using elliptic curve (ECDH[E] or ECDSA, for 1.2), so **yes that is a problem** because [that server only supports ECHDE (actually ECDHE_RSA) suites for 1.2](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=trustspot.io). Java 8 _should_ support EC, unless your JVM is weirdly configured _or_ you are on RedHat-family (including Fedora CentOS etc) build of OpenJDK more than a few years old, because until recently RedHat removed EC. Otherwise look at `JRE/lib/security/java.security` and see if SunEC is in the providers list.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085 it is redhat so I think that is the issue although i dont even have a java.security file for the 1.8.161 version so may it was just corrupted. I have just updated to Java jdk1.8.0_202 and now working, if you post comment as answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my Java version, (answer came from @dave_thompson_085 comment, I don't fully understand the details so forgive me if not explained totally correctly)

I was using Java 1.8.0_161-b12 on a linux centos machine, turns out this version doesnt support elliptic curve suites for TLS 1.2, but the server I was connecting to only supports ECHDE and this requires use of elliptic curve algorithm so therefore would not work.

Updated to jdk1.8.0_202 and now working

Comment: We are using  jdk 1.8.0_3xx at server, here we are facing the same exception at Java 11 client which is using Apache HttpClient5.x version. ANy suggestion, how to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

generally SSL issues are related to certificate problems, are you sure you old certificate still holds valid and properly configured, if not the i suggest to add it in the server first

Comment: My SSL certiificate is fine ( you can check by going to the SSL version of my website https://www.jthink.net). But anyway in this case isnt it irrelvant because my server is acting as the client talking to the trustpot server, and in my code I dont even mention SSL since it is the same code and I didnt even have an SSL certificate on my old server.

Comment: okay, on futher notice i can see that close_notify issue. javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake indicates the termination of the ssl connection. This issue can depend on the performance of the machine and due to network issues.

Comment: nothing much is happening on the machine its not a performance issue

Comment: Added SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()) and got output SSLv2Hello SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2, I read somewhere there could be some issue about what TLS version the server (i.e trustpot end) supports, not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8.0_161-b12

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626500/what-is-received-close-notify-during-handshake-error says I was able to fix the issue by upgrading Java to Java SE 8. The issue was caused because the server was expecting the SSL protocol if TLSv1.1 which isn't available in Java 1.6 which was being used by the client. After updating to Java 8 and specifying the protocol using https.protocol system variable the error was resolved.

Comment: I'm already on Java 8 but it does seem the server is expecting me to use SSL and I have configured SSL in my connection so maybe that helps pinpoint the issue